# Android App via buildozer: requirements vs. recipes

Tags: pandas, kivy, buildozer, recipe, p4a

i try to deploy an android app. I work with the kivy framework and buildozer in python. My issue is to include the pandas library. This is my simple and working test code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

import pandas as pd

class TestLibraries(App):
    
    def build(self):
        
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df.loc[0, 'text'] = 'this is pandas'
        return Label(text = df.loc[0, 'text'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestLibraries().run()
```

The next step is do define the buildozer .spec file. Here i see two options:

1. Via requirements: So i modify the .spec file like this

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==1.11.1,pandas
```

This works very well.
2. Via recipe: I take the recipe from [github](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/pandas). and put it into my folder called recipe. After that i modify the .spec file like this

```
# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
p4a.local_recipes = /PATH_TO_FOLDER/recipe/
```

In the buildozer logfile i can read:

```
Listing '/PATH_TO_FOLDER/.buildozer/android/app/recipe/pandas'...
Compiling 'PATH_TO_FOLDER/.buildozer/android/app/recipe/pandas/__init__.py'...
```

So buildozer found the recipe but the library is not installed and the app dosen't works.

And the question is: why not?

You might ask me for using the second option because the first option works very well. In the next step i want to write a new recipe. So i have to learn how to include an existing recipe correctly.

I hope you unterstand my problem an have some advices.

Thanks Capa

Comment: I don't think the lines you posted show the recipe being used. Post the full log.

Comment: I would like to post the full log, but "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 1683219." what can i do?

Comment: Use a pastebin site

Comment: Thank you :-) Here it is: https://paste2.org/n39CNzFn

Comment: Can you clean everything, build again, and post a log of the full build?

Comment: "Clean everything" will mean delete the .buildozer folder and deploy again? If yes so i can...

Comment: Here it is: https://paste2.org/IafcCYNw

Comment: `--requirements=python3,kivy==1.11.1 ` <- doesn't look like you're attempting to build pandas

Comment: This is option 1 in the initial problem decription. If i set pandas in the requirements, i don't need to use the recipe. Do you say that i have to set both the requirement and recipe if i want to use a recipe?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what recipes are. They are programmatic build instructions for how to compile pandas for android. When you specify something in your requirements, it is built using a recipe if a recipe is available. If you don't specify something in your requirements, it isn't built/included at all.

Comment: Ok i understand what does it stand for. For my app i need to write a recipe to use the scikit-learn libraries. So i add "scikit-learn" to the requirements and write a recipe called "scikit-learn" to define how to build. Right?

Comment: Yes. Warning in advance: it is probably hard to make a recipe for scikit-learn.

Comment: Is this the reason why such a recipe does not exist? You know why it hard to make that recipe?

Comment: It's probably a relatively complicated library with various compiled components and dependencies that must be carefully navigated.